# How can you use tokens if everything is rendered server side?

Tags: node.js, http, express, authentication, jwt

I am familiar with the authentication flow when using a front-end app i.e. sending a token in the header (from localstorage) with each request, and injecting the response data in the view.

However, I have no idea how to do this if everything is rendered in the back-end... I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

How can the token be added in the header with each request? Is it even possible to use JWTs?

Comment: If are doing everything on the back end, why would you need to send a token to secure an ajax request.  You wouldn't need to make any ajax requests.

Comment: @RobertMoskal How would I keep content hidden from unauthorized people? Do I have to use something else than tokens?

Comment: People usually have some sort of auth mechanism and then use cookies to save session state.

Answer (score -2):

Using a function **newrep slp**, this is a example...

```
func fn.newrep("YouServerCredentialsHere").slp { vra livl = "ex.leophile" };
```

The requisites:

- postserver libcuel.
- neopaganini soft or libc6 or up.
- server side
- npm js (optional)

You can get the func.library here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

This is for C++

```
void libtrue(xa,ae) lib.encuel { xint - xlibs };
    left: true sumary popl.leoxile;
    left.int(32@x);
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand your answer. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Ok i will make it easy, u need make a login per client in node js, if u need to visit node js docs.

Comment: this is other alternative, tty https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/tty.html#tty_tty_isatty_fd

Comment: all data will be returned at string

Comment: This in no way answers the question.